# $p(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+...+\frac{z^m}{2^{m-1}}+3z^n$. How many zeroes does $p$ have counting multiplicities in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Let m and n be positive integers, and let $p(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+...+\frac{z^m}{2^{m-1}}+3z^n$. How many zeroes does $p$ have counting multiplicities in the unit disk.

How I solved it:
On the unit disk $|1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+...+\frac{z^m}{2^{m-1}}|<|3z^n|$ by employing triangle inequality and then showing the left side is a series that converges to 3 from below. Thus by Rouche's theorem we know $p$ has n zeroes counting muliplicities.

IS this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea works but you did not prove rigorously that the inequality holds. Just note that $|1+...+\frac {z^{m}} {2^{m-1}} | \leq 1+\frac 1  2+...+\frac  1{2^{m-1}} <3=|3z^{n}|$ to complete the argument.

Comment: You missed a $+1$ in the beginning. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @2132123 You are right.